# Pythagorean triplets whose sum is 1000?

Tags: c++, pythagorean

Project Euler problem 9. I tried to solve it, infact I get triplets which are not Pythagorean triplets and their sum is 1000, Why? I made sure they were Pythagorean triplets. Here is my long and not so optimized code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b,c; //Decalring the triplets...
    a=1; //First triplet starts with 3
    b=1;
    int c2;//c square

    while(true)
    {
        for(b=1;b<a;b++){
        c2 = a*a+b*b;
        c = sqrt(c2);
        if(c*c == c2 && a+b+c==1000)
        {
            cout<<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<<"\n";
        }
        a++;
        }
        b++;
    }
}
```

Final working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y,z,a;
    for(x=1;x<=1000;x++)
    {
        for(y=1;y<=1000;y++)
        {
            a = x*x+y*y;
            z=sqrt(a);
            if(z*z==a && x+y+z==1000 && x<y){
            cout<<x<<","<<y<<","<<z<<"."<<"\n";
            cout<<"So the product of all of the three triplets is "<<x*y*z;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking that `sqrt(c2)` is integral?

Comment: I did, It gives me no result then... :/

Answer (score 2):

Your loop conditions are off. The `c` corresponding to the current `a` and `b` is computed *inside* the loop. Therefore, you cannot test the loop iteration on the value of `c` because it's an old one. Remove `c` from the conditions, put back the test for integrality of `sqrt(c2)`, and you have a solution.

**EDIT**

You seem to be trying to get results by doing more or less random code changes. That is *not* going ot get you anywhere.

Start by clearly formulating your algorithm in plain human language. Then re-word it into a (still plain human language) structure matching C++ code concepts. Then code those concepts.

Something like this:

Step 1. In a Pythagorean triplet, the third member `c` is fully determined by the first two. So I will examine all possible values of `a` and `b`, and if they form a Pythagorean triplet, test it for sum of 1000.

Step 2. For each `a`, I will test all `b`s larger than the `a` such that `a + b` is less than 1000. I will compute `c2` and see if it's a square. If so, I will test the sum of the triplet.

Step 3.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  for (int a = 3; a < 1000; ++a) {
    for (int b = a + 1; a + b < 1000; ++b) {
      int c2 = a * a + b * b;
      int c = std::sqrt(c2);
      if (c * c == c2) {
        if (a + b + c == 1000) {
          std::cout << "Found triplet " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << '\n';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rohanchrome Well, now you're only testing triplets where `b == a + 1`. You should loop `b` as well.

Comment: Thanks man! That did it! :D
I started out fresh and it worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

You should check to make sure that `c2` is actually a square. One way of doing this is to check whether `c*c == c2` after you've taken the square root.

Comment: Thanks I tried it, But that gives me no result :/
Probably something wrong with my logic?

Comment: @Rohanchrome: The loop condition on the outermost loop looks fishy. `a` and `c` will change in response to `b` within the loop, so you should probably only be checking `b` in the condition of the `while` loop.

Comment: What should be the condition? b<=1000?

Comment: @Rohanchrome: It can be made stricter than that (hint: use the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)), but yes, that should work, I think.

Comment: I re-coded it making it very simple, and to calculate the triplets only, Slight change in the logic, I updated the post... I used just true as the condition so the loop goes on but prints only if the condition is satisfied...

Comment: @Rohanchrome: Where did the second loop go? You want two nested loops; one for `a` and one for `b`.

Comment: Although if I remove the condition a+b+c==1000 the I get results?? Which is weird :/

Comment: What is the simplest thing that could possibly work? Two loops both going from 1 to 1000. The inner `if` will discard anything that doesn't work. Once you've got that working, you can try to be more clever by using identities such as `a < b`, `a + b + c <= 1000` and the triangle inequality, or even [Euclid's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), but there is no shame in starting simple. And for this small problem, it'll likely be more than fast enough in either case.

Answer (score 1):

```
//My brute force solution works fine
since i<j<k
start j loop from i+1 and k loop from j+1
whenever the condition satisfies print the product of triplet

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(long long i=1;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        for(long long j=i+1;j<=1000;j++)
        {
            for(long long k=j+1;k<=1000;k++)
            {
                if((i+j+k)==1000 && i*i+j*j==k*k)
                {
                cout<<i*j*k<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is considered bad style by some, to answer with uncommented code and no explaining text.